# How to differentiate between an import and a function definition in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a python function that searches through a list of files looking for ones with a specific decorator. I grab the modules through:

```py
# Load modules from files
loader = machinery.SourceFileLoader(file_name, file_path)
spec = util.spec_from_loader(loader.name, loader)
module = util.module_from_spec(spec)
loader.exec_module(module)

# fetch functions
functions = [function for function in dir(module)]
```

But I have the following problem:

file1.py

```py
@dork
def does_something():
   pass
```

---

file2.py

```py
from file1 import does_something
```

So when I'm searching for the decorator, I'm getting both paths:
'file1.does_something'
'file2.does_something'

When I only want the path at file1. Is there a way to distinguish between actual functions and an import?

Comment: An easy fix would be just `import file1` and then use `file1.does_something`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How to differentiate between an import and a function definition in python?" That isn't a distinction at the level you are analyzing this. The *same function object* exists in the namespaces of two *different module objects*. This is a distinction that would require analysis of the *source code*, not the module object.

Here is one potential hack, though, check if:

```
func.__module__ == module.__name__
```